# Service worker sync fires immediately, no matter internet connection

Tags: service-worker

I have this listener for sync in the service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
    if (event.tag === 'button-click') {
        console.log('SYNC for button-click triggered!');
        console.log(event);
        event.waitUntil(
            fetch('https://localhost/')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                })
                .then(function(html) {
                    console.log('Fetching successful');
                    console.log(html);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('Fetching failed');
                    console.log(err);
                })

        );
    }
});
```

So when I click on the button - the console.logs and the fetch works fine.

The problem is that when I turn off the connection and click the button - the console.logs and the fetch get triggered immediately `again`.
Shouldn't they wait for the page to get connection again and `then` do the console.logs and the fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Mega lame problem :D

I was using the `offline` checkbox in `Chrome` ... which appears to be `NOT WORKING`.

So when I started to disconnect and re-connect the whole laptop to the wifi - then I got the correct behavior.

Conclusion: `Always doubt the browser!!!`